# Serial port running on a thread using MVP

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, serial-port, mvp

I have a class called `SerialClient` that sends/receives bytes over a serial port. When `SerialClient.Start()` is called it goes into an infinite while loop, until `SerialClient.Stop()` is called. The class has some properties, for simplicity lets say `SerialClient.PropA`, `SerialClient.PropB`.

I need to use this in a GUI. Where by on the GUI you can call Start, Stop and read the properties as they change.

In order to use this in a GUI, obviously `SerialClient` needs to operate in a thread as its an endless loop. So, I have setup the view with properties to match that of `SerialClient`. The view calls `Start()` and `Stop()` on the presenter.

In the presenter I create a new thread and call start on an object of `SerialClient`. The problem is when _serialClient throws an exception the presenter cannot catch it, and also if the properties like (`SerialClient.PropB`) change and call their changed event handlers, they need to be invoked on the GUI thread. I tried using the background worker, but couldn't get it working (changing properties still hit the UI from the non-UI thread).

```
Thread thread = new Thread(_serialClient.Start);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

There must a simple solution I am over looking. The GUI just needs to call methods and read properties, and prevent exceptions crashing the whole application.

Any ideas?

Comment: ¿Are you handling ErrorReceived and DataReceived?

Comment: On the .Net SerialPort class? If so no. Within SerialClient class. There is an OpenCOM() method. This creates a SerialPort (_comport) on COM5 with correct settings, then opens it. All of this is within Start() OpenCOM() is called, then a new thread is made is made on the method SendReceivedData, which contains the endless loop. In here i loop round reading _comport.BytesToRead, if there is data then _comport.Read(/*read in data here*/), else if there is data to send then use _comport.Write(/*my data here*/).

Comment: Yes, to read bytes do not use a loop just try with DataReceived event and ErrorRecieved for the errors if you can, then when DataReceived is called by serialport you can read all data and Invoke a delegate.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out. But i have two questions.

1) Who should start the thread? Should it be done in the presenter or should SerialClient.Start() be responsible for creating the thread. 

2) If errors occurs in the com port, i.e. power loss breaks the connection, COM5 doesn't exist, these throw exceptions instead of ErrorRecieved events. These will not be caught on the UI thread and crash the application. I need to raise exception to the UI to notify the user. I.e. "The COM port you selected is in use by another application".

Comment: I believe I need to use ISynchronizeInvoke to handle this issue, but it is not available in the Compact Framework. The code library must be GUI independent so I can't hack in a solution by including a control. The only way it can be done is to write invoke handlers for everything when using the Compact framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit 2 of the common problems usually seen when dealing with multithreaded application in C#:

1. Dealing with exception in the background thread. When exceptions occurs in the background thread, they travel up the stack, from caller to caller to see if anyone is able to catch that exception. If the original call occurs from outside your own calls (for example, a callback from a serial port or a timer) you may or may not be notified of the exception. As a typical solution to this, what I have seen is to wrap in a try-catch the code that can throw the exception and to have an event handler push the exception to a thread that will be able to handle the exception appropriately (log, notify the user, terminate, all of the above)
2. Events are always excuted on the thread that calls them. You have to manually marshall the call to the UI thread using Dispatcher and Invoke. The most succint code to do it I found is [here](http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/Use-WPF-Dispatcher-to-invoke-event-handler-only-when-needed.aspx)

```
 
 void someEvent_Handler(object sender, SomeEventEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        // do work on UI thread
    }
    else
    {
        // or BeginInvoke()
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(someEvent_Handler), 
            sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've since made this change. I have the start method contain the code to start the thread, so the APi to others is easier. Then i have an event called ExceptionRaised. This is called when an exception is raised that would escape the threaded method. This way the exception is caught and stopped, the thread stops and an event is raised. I think this is the best solution, but I really throught there were better methods. I have looked into invoking onto the GUI thread, but the interfaces required are not in the compact framework.